# What does the theme_comment_thread_expanded function do in the drupal comment module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

```
function theme_comment_thread_expanded($comment, $node) {

    $links = module_invoke_all('link', 'comment', $comment, 0);

    drupal_alter('link', $links, $node, $comment);

    return theme('comment_view', $comment, $node, $links);

}
```

I don't understand this function well. I hope someone here can help explain it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It gathers links for comments from all modules that implement the hook_link() and formats them with theme functions (theme_comment_view).

**Edit:**
To clarify (and to include jp's comment):

```
$links = module_invoke_all('link', 'comment', $comment, 0);
```

This calls the `hook_link()` function for all modules that implement it (that is `modulename_link()`) with the function arguments 'comment', $comment and 0. Those modules return links to be put underneath comments (e.g the quote module returns a link for adding comments with the previous one quoted). The function `module_invoke_all()` accumulated these links and returns them.

```
drupal_alter('link', $links, $node, $comment);
```

This call is similar to the previous one. It calls modules which implement `hook_link_alter()` and lets them alter the links.

```
return theme('comment_view', $comment, $node, $links);
```

This one calls the theme hook "comment_view" to format the comment links. There will usually be a default implementation of this hook and themes can override it.

The whole function `theme_comment_thread_expanded()` can be overridden as well (e.g. `yourtheme_comment_thread_expanded()`).

Comment: in the middle of those two steps it also invokes any [hook_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link_alter/6)'s